# Create page that displays Codeigniter log files on webpage

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

I have an admin page that I would like for all of the log messages that are created in my Codeigniter's application/log folder to be displayed on the page. That way I don't have to go into the actual file to view them and could look at them by logging into my site and clicking the Logs page.

Is this possible?

Comment: Function calls [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way I have my error_log and also displayed on the view

As @Tpojka suggested `file_get_contents($file, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH, null);`

```
<?php

class Error_log extends CI_Controller {


    public function index() {   
        $data['title'] = 'Error Log';

        $data['clear'] = site_url('tool/error_log/clear');

        $data['log'] = '';

         // Current Filename;
        $file = FCPATH . 'application/logs/' . 'log-'.date('Y-m-d').'.php';

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            $size = filesize($file);

            if ($size >= 5242880) {
                $suffix = array(
                    'B',
                    'KB',
                    'MB',
                    'GB',
                    'TB',
                    'PB',
                    'EB',
                    'ZB',
                    'YB'
                );

                $i = 0;

                while (($size / 1024) > 1) {
                    $size = $size / 1024;
                    $i++;
                }

                $error_warning = 'Warning: Your error log file %s is %s!';

                $data['error_warning'] = sprintf($error_warning, basename($file), round(substr($size, 0, strpos($size, '.') + 4), 2) . $suffix[$i]);
            } else {

                 // Updated from comment

                $log = file_get_contents($file, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH, null); 
                $lines = explode("\n", $log); 
                $content = implode("\n", array_slice($lines, 1)); 
                $data['log'] = $content;
            }
        }

        $this->load->view('header', $data)
        $this->load->view('error_log', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

}
```

**Error Log View**

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <textarea wrap="off" rows="15" readonly class="form-control"><?php echo $log; ?></textarea>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the log path as default on config.php but you can set it to what you need.

```
$config['log_path'] = '';

$config['log_threshold'] = 2;
```

Sample Preview

[image]

Comment: That is perfect! Did you remove the first line that has the `<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>` so that it's not displayed on the screen?

Comment: I have not done that part yet where you remove `<?php` but would be possible just learning my self.

Comment: I have looked around on google and that is how I found the code above and then converted it to codeigniter.

Comment: I found this and it seems to have worked, replaced everything in your last else  `$log = file_get_contents($file, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH, null);
                
    $lines = explode("\n", $log);
    $content = implode("\n", array_slice($lines, 1));
    
    $this->data['log'] = $content;`