# How to add some styling to log file in CI

Tags: codeigniter, logging, formatting

I am using CodeIgniter for a little while and I want to add some styling to the CI log system.

Why did I need to add some styling in the log file?

```
1. CI log messages system is very congested.
2. message formats are not tidy enough.
```

What do I want to add in CI log file?

```
1. Different indication for different log messages.
2. Align the log messages so we can see and understand properly.
3. Highlight some messages for references.
```

So,  What the changes should I have to do in the log file or maybe I should drop this idea of changing the log messages formats and styling.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726303/create-page-that-displays-codeigniter-log-files-on-webpage

Comment: @shafiq sir I Just checked your suggested link. thank for that.

Comment: But can't we make the log file little more appropriate, and more managed messages? @shafiq

Comment: Yes you can. 
It depend on you how you want to display your log file.

Check these links to 
https://github.com/ppcat/codeigniter-log-viewer
https://github.com/seirotsirK/Codeigniter_Log_Viewer
https://github.com/bronskidev/ci-logviewer

Hope it will help you